# A button in a kendo ui grid doesn't work on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an example, a kendo ui grid is added with Backbone.js. In the kendo ui grid I have a buttons to remove rows, but the buttons don't work on mobile devices. If I press a button repeteadly, it sometimes works. Why?
I declare the button in kendoGrid.columns so:

```
{
command: [{
     name: "destroy",
     text: "Remove",
     className: "ob-delete"
}
```

To remove a row and do something when button is clicked:

```
$(document).on("click", ".grid tbody tr .ob-delete", function (e) {
    var item = grid.dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
    var check = confirm("Delete");
    if (check) {
        grid.removeRow($(this).closest("tr"));
    }
});
```

[Full example](http://jsfiddle.net/vicenrele/Thxtr/48/)

Edit:

I use the kendo ui version: 2012.3.1114

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile and click event are not best of friends!

In this code you are adding click on the Html element having .ob-delete class which will not fire Kendo's built in click event. Instead, try to implement your delete method as custom command shown in this demo: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/custom-command.html

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
                var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                       pageSize: 10,
                       data: createRandomData(50)
                    },
                    pageable: true,
                    height: 260,
                    columns: [
                        { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name" },
                        { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name" },
                        { field: "Title" },
                        { command: { text: "View Details", click: showDetails }, title: " ", width: "140px" }]
                }).data("kendoGrid");

                wnd = $("#details")
                    .kendoWindow({
                        title: "Customer Details",
                        modal: true,
                        visible: false,
                        resizable: false,
                        width: 300
                    }).data("kendoWindow");

                detailsTemplate = kendo.template($("#template").html());
            });

            function showDetails(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
                wnd.content(detailsTemplate(dataItem));
                wnd.center().open();
            }
        </script>
```

or if a custom command is not required, try the default delete event as shown in this demo. 
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-inline.html

Comment: I use the kendo ui version: 2012.3.1114, and the example doesn't work.  The exmaple: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vicenrele/Lu9Qf/3/)

Comment: In your jsfiddle example quite a bit of things were missing from the example like the template for rendering, div placeholder for the details template etc. Ive fixed the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lu9Qf/17/ . its fully working now.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've another problem with kendo ui grids, maybe you could help me: [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892406/reloading-kendo-ui-grid-the-row-item-code-executes-an-error)